# How to find the rate of change of the side length of a cube at time $t$ if the cube retains its shape as it melts

Tags: calculus

Question: A perfect cube of ice retains its shape as it melts at a constant rate of $3~\text{cm}^3$/min. The cube of ice has an initial side length of $4$ cm. Write an expression for the rate of change of the side length $x$ of the ice cube of any time $t$.

Can someone please give me some tips?

Could this be a composite function question? What exactly is the rate of change?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decrease in the volume is by $3cm^3/min$ so we formulate it as - $$dV/dt = -3$$ Substitute $V = x^3$ and by chain rule we can write $$dV/dt = (dV/dx)(dx/dt)$$ therefore $$dV/dt = (3x^2)(dx/dt)$$
Substituting in the first equation we get - $$dx/dt = -(1/x^2)cm/min$$
This is the required rate of decrease of the side of the ice cube. Solving this differential equation for $x$, it will be clear how the side length varies(decreases) with time $t$.

Solving this differential equation to get $x(t)$ considering it as an Initial Value problem with the given condition of $x(0)=4cm$, we get $$x(t) = (64-3t)^{1/3} cm$$

Comment: I get the impression, from the level of the question, that leaving an unsolved differential equation does not makes things much easier.

Comment: The question was asked specifically for the "rate of change of side"!

Comment: More specifically, "the rate of change of the side length $x$ of the ice cube **of any time $t$**". I take that to mean that the question wants $\mathrm{d}x / \mathrm{d}t$ in terms of $t$. The initial value given for $x$ confirms this in my mind.

Comment: Edited the answer. Thank you

Comment: @TheoBendit yes you are correct, nevertheless, this is a great answer thanks!

Comment: @FredWeasley Ah, well if it helps you, then I'm happy. +1

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Siddhant.

Initial volume is $64$ cc and the volume is decreasing at a rate of $3$ cc per minute. That means volume as a function of $t$ is
$$V(t)=64-3t$$
Taking the cube root gives the length of side
$$x(t) = \sqrt[3]{64-3t}$$
Differentiate above to get rate of change of $x$ as a function of $t$.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a solution which is a bit easier:

> Write an expression for the rate of change of the side length x of the ice cube of any time t.

This tells us that we should come up with a function $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $t \in [0,\infty)$ the expression $f(t)$ denotes the side length of the ice cube.
Now the above quote simply asks for $f'$.

> The cube of ice has an initial side length of 4 cm.

This tells us that $f(0) = 4 \text{ (cm)}$. I'll omit the units from now on in mathematical expressions.

> it melts at a constant rate of 3 cm³/min.

Now comes the composite function part! This sentence tells us what the rate of change *of the volume* is! Not of $f$ -- since $f$ gives us the side length. To formalize this sentence, let us hence define a function for the volume: $g: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g = f^3$. Explictily, this means that for all $t \in [0,\infty)$ we have $g(t) = (f(t))^3$.

The sentence now translates to $g'(t) = -3$ for all $t \in [0,\infty)$. We infer that $g$ is a linear function of the form $g(t) = -3t + b$. Above we were told that the initial side length was 4 cm. This means the initial volume $g(0) = a\cdot 0 + b = b = 4³$. Hence we have $g(t) = -3t + 4³$.

Finally, we seek $f$ to compute $f'$. Therefore we exploit the relationship $g(t) = (f(t))^3$ and get $$f(t) = (g(t))^{\frac{1}{3}} = (-3t + 4³)^{\frac{1}{3}}.$$

As a last step, we take the derivative and get $$f'(t) = \frac{1}{3} (-3t + 4^3)^{-\frac{2}{3}} \cdot (-3) = -(-3t + 4^3)^{-\frac{2}{3}}.$$

---

Bonus question: At which time $t^\ast$ has the cube fully melted?

> For this we solve $g(t^\ast) = 0$ and get $t^\ast = \frac{4^3}{3} = 21.333\ldots$.

Bonus question II: Why does $f'(t)$ go to negative infinity for $t$ approaching $t^\ast$? Formally, why do we have $$\lim_{t\to t^\ast} f(t) = -\infty ?$$

This is a plot of $f'$:

[image: Plot of f' over the domain [0, 21.33...)]

Answer (score 0):

If you let $x$ be the length of a side of the cube at time $t,$ then its volume at any instant of time is $x^3,$ since it is always a cube (it retains its shape throughout the change). The rate of change of volume with time is therefore $3x^2x',$ which we're told is constantly $-3$ (negative because the volume is reducing, since the ice is melting) for all time. Thus, we have the differential equation $3x^2x'=-3,$ or equivalently $$x^2x'=-1.$$ This is the expression needed, in terms of $x(t).$

We are told that for some initial point of time $t=t_0,$ we have that $x(t_0)=4.$ I suspect this is for the second part of the problem, but I'll not touch it since you do not mention it.